# Cordova - iOS nested element disable bounce but keep velocity scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, scroll

I have a Cordova app which has a scrollable content on one of the screens. I have a `div` with `overflow:scroll` and `-webkit-overflow-scroll:touch` and all is well. Velocity scrolling (native-style) works fine. This is on iOS 9.3. The `html` and `body` do not scroll (`height:100%` and `overflow:hidden`).

The problem I'm having is the "bounce" effect both when the scrolling has momentum and hits the start/end, and when the user continues pulling on the content. I want to disable both the momentum bounce and the user-pull bounce, while maintaining velocity scrolling. I've tried all of the solutions that I've been able to find online so far:

- Adding prefs to config.xml - `DisallowOverscroll`, `webviewbounce`, `UIWebViewBounce`
- CSS changes - combinations of `overflow` on parent/child
- JavaScript acrobatics - catching `touchstart` and calling `preventDefault` under certain conditions, resetting `scrollTop` to 0, etc. etc.
- Native code changes - settings `bounces` to `no`, iterating over "SubViews"

None of these work. Some JS solutions KIND OF worked, but in a very glitchy way (shaking, flicker, etc.).

Any ideas are much appreciated!!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I came close by using JavaScript and switching the `-webkit-overflow-scroll` style depending on whether the scroll position is at the edge, but it's glitchy.

Comment: is this still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your config.xml

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```